# detect form field ids or names in sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, forms, sharepoint

Hi I am new to SharePoint 2010 and have researched this question and this is what I came up with, and I'm still confused.  I wrote the following code in notepad and put it in my site assets library, which I linked to my list form through the content editor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i=0; i<tags.length; i++){

    document.write(tags[i].name + "<br />");
}
//-->
</script>
```

Then this is the output I get:

```
MSOWebPartPage_PostbackSource

MSOTlPn_SelectedWpId

MSOTlPn_View

MSOTlPn_ShowSettings

MSOGallery_SelectedLibrary

MSOGallery_FilterString
```

Well, it's the first few return values.  I was expecting something like "Title" for the form title, "Author" for the Created by field, etc.  My end goal is to have a field hidden upon inital creation with a default value.  When being edited (by someone with higher permissions), the field will be visible.  So I'm just trying to figure out how to access form elements first.  Thanks!

Comment: _“I was expecting something like "Title" for the form title, "Author" for the Created by field, etc.”_ – looks like you are confusing the contents of the `name` attribute with a description for the input elements that is placed elsewhere in the HTML (f.e. inside a `label`).

Comment: Thanks, but I just checked using javascript and there are no `label` tags in the form.  I just want to know how I can access a form input and set its value or css